# Same first digit

Tags: exponentiation

We raise the numbers 2 and 5 to the same positive integer power and get two numbers that have the same first (leftmost) digit. What are the possible values of the first digit?

Comment: Well... I believe the only possible number is 3.

Comment: First as in leftmost or rightmost?

Comment: @John:  for the rightmost the only answer is $1$ with the power being $0$.

Comment: I don't know how to find the first digit... If it were possible to have the total number n of digits (length of number) and then divide by 10^(n-1) and then round down the quotient...

Comment: Just thinking out loud: We can also take the logarithm "L" of the number, take its integer part "i" and then divide by 10^i, then round down the quotient. I don't know if any of these things make sense!

Comment: @RossMillikan 10^n. So we express 5 as 10/2? And then raise to the same power?

Comment: That is correct.  Now you need two numbers with the same first digit that multiply to $10^n$.  One choice is $100 \times 1000$ or something similar, but those are never powers of $2$ and $5$.  Can you find another choice?  If you don't see it right away, just start listing $2^n, 5^n$ and see when they start with the same digit.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see they have the same first digit when the power is 5, 15, 78, 88, 98, 108 and so on.

Comment: ...but I still don't get it :( :(

Comment: We know that the leading digits of $2^n$ and $5^n$ are the same and that the product starts with $1000\ldots$.  If they leading digits of $2^n$ and $5^n$ were $6$, for example, we would have $36\ldots \le 2^n5^n \lt 49 \ldots$.  The only leading digit that includes $1000\ldots$ is $3$ because we know the product is between $9\ldots $ and $16\ldots$  We need the leading digit to be about $\sqrt {10}$ and $3$ qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  what is the product $2^n \cdot 5^n?$